# Statistics based image processing

Tags: statistical-significance, bayesian

I have a question in Bayesian based image processing tasks. When I was going through some papers, I found that distribution fitting can be used to choose the prior for the model? Why it is useful since observed data = target data+noise. How come the prior (information about target data) distribution can be chosen as a fitted distribution? My point of view fitted distribution is the distribution of the observed data, right?then how do I choose the likelihood? Can we choose the  fitted distribution act as a likehood? I am totally confused. Please let me know the correct way of dealing with.

All the answers are appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question, so I will give a very general answer.

Typically in [computer vision](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=16605107453260999726) the prior is based on characteristics of natural images that tend to be seen in practice. This is commonly referred to as a ["natural image prior"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=natural%20image%20prior). One example would be coherence, i.e. neighboring pixels *tend* to be similar (e.g. this is why feature detectors/descriptors like [SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) look for things like corners, which are "interest points" *because* the smoothness prior is violated).

In the simplest case, which is common in practice, the Bayesian approach might use [MAP estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation). This combines the [data likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) given the parameters with the *a-priori likelihood* of the parameters. In general the prior is interpreted as prior information about the un-observed *parameters*, rather than the *data*, which is observed.

**Note:** I mainly learned about these things from the [Szeliski E-book](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=16605107453260999726) (free online), which I highly recommend if you are interested in more details.